# How to do a Vlookup/Index-Match?

Tags: excel, vba

I get 1004 error when trying to do a Vlookup/Index-Match, or no results at all.

I tried both vlookup and Index /match inside a While loop.

I have used basically the same loop in many of my macros without any issues so far. I tried adjusting the formats (even with Format painter).

I isolated the values for the lookup in a new file and did just the lookup part.

Note: A manual Vlookup or index.Match works.

Code:

```
Sub lookup()

 'Variables for the Vlookups
 Dim newRow As Long
 Dim newCL As String

 newRow = 7

 Dim rn As Range
 Set rn = Worksheets("trysheet").Range("C:C")
 Dim mrange As Range
 Set mrange = Worksheets("trysheet").Range("A:A")

 On Error Resume Next
 'lookups
 Do While Worksheets("test").Cells(newRow, 4).Value <> ""
 newCL = Worksheets("test").Cells(newRow, 4).Value
 Worksheets("test").Cells(newRow, 5) = Application.Index(rn, 
 Application.Match(newCL, mrange, 0))
 newRow = newRow + 1
 Loop

End Sub
```

I have tried using Application.WorksheetFunction instead of just Application. but then I either receive

> 1004 error - "Unable to get Match/Vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class"

or

> Application defined error

EDIT:
I achieved the required result using the traditional vlookup function (with the help of macro recording and modifying my loop):

```
Sub lookup()

'Variables for the Vlookups
Dim newRow As Long

newRow = 7

Dim rn As Range
Set rn = Worksheets("trysheet").Range("C:C")
Dim mrange As Range
Set mrange = Worksheets("trysheet").Range("A:A")

On Error Resume Next
'
'Get Employee
Do While Worksheets("test").Cells(newRow, 4).Value <> ""
 Worksheets("test").Cells(newRow, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], trysheet!C[-4]:C[-2],3,0)"
 newRow = newRow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

I usually try to avoid this method and stick to the application.WorksheetFunction or application.Vlookup(example) because I find it more clean and automatically removes the formula, but in this case does the job.

Still help me understand why the application method did not work here, because this happens to me for the first time.

yytsunamiyy had some good suggestions below, but still not complete.

Comment: Is the value of newCL present in myrange?

Comment: Hi Nathan, yes, newCL is in mrange, in fact in my case all values which newCL will take will be matched...

Answer (score 0):

Your Index formula is missing a column reference, try:

```
Worksheets("test").Cells(newRow, 5) = Application.Index(rn, Application.Match(newCL, mrange, 0),1)
```

following the discussion below here my solution:

It seems that your sheet references and therefor your ranges are incorrect. Best practice is to use the codenames of sheets rather than the display names to reference sheets. Here an example of how to do this and how you would use it in your procedure:

```
Public shTest As Worksheet
Public shTrySheet As Worksheet

Sub run_lookups()

    Call defineVars
    Call lookup_newrow

End Sub

Sub defineVars()

    Dim sh As Worksheet

        For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            Select Case sh.CodeName
                Case "Test"
                    Set shTest = sh
                Case "TrySheet"
                    Set shTrySheet = sh
            End Select
        Next sh

End Sub

Sub lookup_newrow()

    'Variables for the Vlookups
     Dim newRow As Long
     Dim newCL As String

        newRow = 7

    Dim rn As Range
        Set rn = shTrySheet.Range("C:C")
    Dim mrange As Range
        Set mrange = shTrySheet.Range("A:A")

 'On Error Resume Next
 'lookups
    Do While shTest.Cells(newRow, 4).Value <> ""
        newCL = shTest.Cells(newRow, 4).Value
        shTest.Cells(newRow, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(rn, Application.Match(newCL, mrange, 0), 1)
        newRow = newRow + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Even more elegant is the solution to simply write the proper formula in R1C1 Format into the range. If you need fixed values simply do a copy and pastespecial.

```
Public shTest As Worksheet
Public shTrySheet As Worksheet

Sub run_lookups2()

    Call defineVars2
    Call lookup_values

End Sub

Sub defineVars2()

    Dim sh As Worksheet

        For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            Select Case sh.CodeName
                Case "Test"
                    Set shTest = sh
                Case "TrySheet"
                    Set shTrySheet = sh
            End Select
        Next sh

End Sub

Sub lookup_values()
   Dim rLookupResults As Range
   Dim sName As String

    sName = shTrySheet.Name 'Sheet is referenced through codename, which is unlikely to get changed, but for fomula displayed sheetname is used

    With shTest

        Set rLookupResults = .Range(.Cells(7, 5), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row, 5))

        'enter LOOKUP() Formula in Lookup Rsult Rang
        rLookupResults.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(LOOKUP(RC[-1]," & sName & "!C[-4]," & sName & "!C[-2]),"""")"

        'if fixed values are need copy and pastespecial
            rLookupResults.Copy
            rLookupResults.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is column optional?

Comment: If you are using the INDEX() formula in the spreadsheet and you have a one-column range column is optional - but then you can simply use LOOKUP() for the same result in that case. However, I have found in the past that sometimes you have to define normally optional variables when using application.worksheetformula.

Comment: Hi guys, tried that as well, in fact i started that with a 3-column range and referenced the 3rd column as argument for the Index. But as it didnt work i switched to 1 dimensional ranges...

Comment: Hi, please see my edited answer. if this solves your problem I would be happy if you would mark the answer as accepted, if not feel free to elaborate.

Comment: Hey, thanks very much but i am afraid this does not work as well, i get an error on this line: Set rn = shTrySheet.Range("C:C")

Comment: Did you copy all the code? Did you change the codename of the sheets? To change the codename click on the sheet in the vba editor and change the sheet property "Name" (yes, Microsoft products can be confusing, name in vba editor for a sheet is actually sheet.codename).

Comment: Yes did that, and from then one my code does not run.. if you give me an e-mail i can send you the workbook so you can have a look yourself.

Comment: Copy and paste either all of the first or all of rhe second code. Set the codenames of your sheets to "test" and "trysheet". Run the run_lookups procedure (running it with F8 allows you to go through the code line by line). That way the sheets variables are defined and the code should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert a formula to a value, you can do something like this.

```
Do While Worksheets("test").Cells(newRow, 4).Value <> ""
 Worksheets("test").Cells(newRow, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], trysheet!C[-4]:C[-2],3,0)"
 Worksheets("test").Cells(newRow, 5).Value = Worksheets("test").Cells(newRow, 5).Value
 newRow = newRow + 1
Loop
```

other ways

```
 Sub lookup()

     'Variables for the Vlookups
    Dim newRow As Long
    Dim newCL As String
    Dim Mrange As Range
    Dim rn As Range
    newRow = 7
    Set rn = Worksheets("trysheet").Range("C:C")

    Set Mrange = Worksheets("trysheet").Range("A:C") '<~~ A ~ C

    With Worksheets("test")
       Do While .Cells(newRow, 4).Value <> ""
           newCL = .Cells(newRow, 4)
           .Cells(newRow, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(newCL, Mrange, 3, 0)
        newRow = newRow + 1
       Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: First way should work. The second one gives me application defined error.